# Unable to download python packages in python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the installation procedure

```
C:\Python34>python -m pip install simplegui
Downloading/unpacking simplegui
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement simplegui
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for simplegui
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\Tanay\pip\pip.log
```

What would be the exact solution to download python package ?

Comment: The package simplegui has no files on PyPI.

Comment: I am unable to download any packages through above procedure, 'simplegui' is just the example

Answer (score 1):

simplegui is [listed](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplegui/0.1.1) on the Py Package Index, but does not seem to have been uploaded to pypi.  The listing refers to the [simplegui page](http://florian-berger.de/en/software/simplegui/), which in turn has a link to a zip file that one must download, unzip, and install.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough rep to comment, but if you can download the package you need, you can still install it using pip as

```
pip install <path to package folder you downloaded>
```

If you run into any problems with a 2.x package you can always try 2to3 to make the package compatible with 3.x.